# htaccess 301 redirect prestashop multisture/multilanguage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am having a hard time finding a solution to my redirect, I already tried every single combination I found here, but it somehow gets stuck at some stage. I am trying to redirect a language URL to a new domain. The tricky thing is that both domains are using the same root folder, and therefore the same htaccess file. This is what I need:

https://www.olddomain.es/de/ (and all its' contents) redirects to
https://www.newdomain.com/de/ (same structure as on old domain).

Here is what I've tried so far:

Option 1:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/portfolio/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/de/$1
```

So this obviusly did not work, as it creates a redirect loop on the new domains' /de/ URL since it uses the same root folder as the old domain.

Option 2:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.es/de/(.*)$
RewriteRule https://www.newdomain.com/de/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I now added the condition to redirect only from the old domain, but in fact, this combination won't do anything at all.

I think that Option 2 is pointing into the right direction, but I must be missing something in the code. Any ideas?

Comment: there is a typus, option 1 should not read /portfolio/, but /de/. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` contains only the `Host` header. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.es$` ↲ `RewriteRule ^/?de/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/de/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Thanks Deadooshka. I added your code, but still nothing happens, no redirect is happening at all.